# Simple form with cfajaxproxy not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Form is not working, does not post to the database though the CFC or seem to be working with the script. When you click on the PostComment button nothing happens. I just spent a day and tried many, many different things. Different buttons and different code, some made things worse and most just cased errors or refreshed the page. I’m not getting any errors with the code below but nothing happens ether.

Can anyone see what I am doing worng?

#### form

`<CFFORM NAME="PostComment" ID="PostComment" METHOD="POST" onsubmit="return false;">

    <CFINPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="CommentSection" VALUE="#CommentSec#">

    <CFtextarea name="Comment" rows="10" cols="50"></CFtextarea>

    <CFINPUT type="image" name="Submit" id="PostComment" value="Post Comment" src="images/PostComment.gif" width="70" height="15" onmouseover="src='images/PostCommentOVER.gif'" onmouseout="src='images/PostComment.gif'">

</CFFORM>`

#### script

`<cfajaxproxy cfc="CFC/PostComment" jsclassname="PostCommentCFC">`

`function PostComment() {

var cfc = new PostCommentCFC();

cfc.setCallbackHandler(getComment);

cfc.Comment(true); 
var targetPostCommentResponse = document.getElementById("targetPostCommentResponse").style.display='block';

var targetMakeComment = document.getElementById("targetMakeComment").style.display='none';

$('#OpenMakeCommentResponse').html("make a comment");

$('#CloseMakeCommentResponse').html("");

return false;

}`

#### CFC PostComment

```
<cfcomponent>  
    <cffunction name="PostComment" access="remote">  
        <cfargument name="CommentSection" type="string" required="true" />  
        <cfargument name="Comment" type="string" required="true" />   
        <CFQUERY NAME="Comment" DATASOURCE="MyDSN"> 
            INSERT INTO Comments(ID,Comment,CommentSection,CommentDate) 
            VALUE (#COOKIE.ID#,'#arguments.Comment#',#arguments.CommentSection#,#Now()#)  
        </CFQUERY>  
        <cfreturn true>   
    </cffunction>  
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't detect anything wrong with your code and I use cfajaxproxy extensively.  It is probably something little.

I would debug using firebug and the coldfusion extension to firebug called coldfire available at RIAForge http://riaforge.org and use the debugger for Cold Fusion available if you are using ColdFusion Builder and to a lesser extent as part of cfeclipse.

Good luck